# Getting predict.proba from BERT classififer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I have a classifier on top of BERT, and I would like to see the predict probability for creating the ROC curve. How do I get the predict proba?. The predicted probas will be used to calculate the TPR FPR and threshold for ROC curve. 
here is the code

```
class BertBinaryClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dropout=0.1):
        super(BertBinaryClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(768, 1)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
        
    
    def forward(self, tokens, masks=None):
        _, pooled_output = self.bert(tokens, attention_mask=masks, output_all_encoded_layers=False)
        dropout_output = self.dropout(pooled_output)
        linear_output = self.linear(dropout_output)
        prediction = self.sigmoid(linear_output)
        return prediction
# Config setting
BATCH_SIZE = 4
EPOCHS = 5
# Making dataloaders
train_dataset =  torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(train_tokens_tensor, train_masks_tensor, train_y_tensor)
train_sampler =  torch.utils.data.RandomSampler(train_dataset)
train_dataloader =  torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, sampler=train_sampler, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
test_dataset =  torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(test_tokens_tensor, test_masks_tensor, test_y_tensor)
test_sampler =  torch.utils.data.SequentialSampler(test_dataset)
test_dataloader =  torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset, sampler=test_sampler, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

bert_clf = BertBinaryClassifier()
bert_clf = bert_clf.cuda()
#wandb.watch(bert_clf)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(bert_clf.parameters(), lr=3e-6)

# training 
for epoch_num in range(EPOCHS):
    bert_clf.train()
    train_loss = 0
    for step_num, batch_data in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        token_ids, masks, labels = tuple(t for t in batch_data)
        token_ids, masks, labels = token_ids.to(device), masks.to(device), labels.to(device)
        preds = bert_clf(token_ids, masks)
        loss_func = nn.BCELoss()
        batch_loss = loss_func(preds, labels)
        train_loss += batch_loss.item()
        bert_clf.zero_grad()
        batch_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        #wandb.log({"Training loss": train_loss})
        print('Epoch: ', epoch_num + 1)
        print("\r" + "{0}/{1} loss: {2} ".format(step_num, len(train_data) / BATCH_SIZE, train_loss / (step_num + 1)))

# evaluating on test
bert_clf.eval()
bert_predicted = []
all_logits = []
probs=[]
with torch.no_grad():
    test_loss = 0
    for step_num, batch_data in enumerate(test_dataloader):
        token_ids, masks, labels = tuple(t for t in batch_data)
        token_ids, masks, labels = token_ids.to(device), masks.to(device), labels.to(device)
        logits = bert_clf(token_ids, masks)
        pr=logits.ravel()
        probs+=pr
        loss_func = nn.BCELoss()
        loss = loss_func(logits, labels)
        test_loss += loss.item()
        numpy_logits = logits.cpu().detach().numpy()
        #print(numpy_logits)
        #wandb.log({"Testing loss": test_loss})
        bert_predicted += list(numpy_logits[:, 0] > 0.5)
        all_logits += list(numpy_logits[:, 0])
```

I am able to get the prediction score to calculate the accuracy or f1 score. But not the probability for creating ROC curve.
Thanks

Comment: The output of the network are probabilities (what you called logits but which does not contains logits). This is what you should use to get the ROC curve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `forward`, you:

```
def forward(self, tokens, masks=None):
    _, pooled_output = self.bert(...)             # Get output of BERT
    dropout_output = self.dropout(pooled_output)  
    linear_output = self.linear(dropout_output)   # Take linear combination of outputs
                                                  # (unconstrained score - "logits")

    prediction = self.sigmoid(linear_output)      # Normalise scores 
                                                  # (constrained between [0,1] - "probabilities")
    return prediction
```

Hence the result of calling your model can be directly supplied to calculate the False Positive and True Positive rates e.g:

```py
from sklearn import metrics

...

test_probs = bert_clf(token_ids, masks)
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(labels, test_probs)
roc_auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
```